# How can I stream audio without latency?

Tags: linux, audio, ffmpeg, streaming

I've been playing around with ffmpeg for sending audio to an endpoint and listening to it. This is the command I've used.

`ffmpeg -f pulse -i 1 -f pulse 1`

Where the two "1's" are the indices of my mic and output device as reported by `pacmd list-sources` and `pacmd list-sinks`.

This command allows me to speak into my microphone and hear it back in my speakers, but there's latency. Other parameters like `-tune zerolatency` and stuff don't help.

I know that low latency audio streaming is possible on Linux since apps like Discord work on it. Why is there latency in my command, and what protocol, program, or library should I use to transmit an audio stream?

Comment: Jack is a good framework for low-latency programming on Linux